# Invisible folders in Android Studio Project view

Tags: android-studio

I have recently switched to Android Studio and try to migrate an ADT project.
In the app/src/main/res/ directory I have the values, values-v11 and values-v14 folder. But in the Studio's Project view only the "values" folder is displayed. Why? How to resolve this?

Comment: In Android Studio: There is an option in the gear icon in the explorer. Enable the option for Show Excluded Files. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153399/8094969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio puts them by default into one view, physically there are still in different folders. If you want to change this, just change the project perspective in the project view on the left side.

Comment: How does this enable viewing hidden folders?